# Excel pivot table grouping issue with 1904 date system

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013, pivot-table

When I use 1904 date system in an Excel workbook I experience a pivot table grouping issue.

After grouping for a date field in pivot table, the date values are shifted by one day.

An example of the issue:

[image: Source table]

[image: Pivot table with and without grouping for the date field]

This issue occurs only with 1904 date system switched on.

**My questions are:**

1. Is there a way to use pivot table date based grouping feature together with 1904 date system?
2. Are there any official documentation about this issue.
3. Are there any other limitations or drawbacks of using 1904 date system?

Comment: i assume thats because of the fact 1900 wasnt a leap year... it will convert it to +4  jears and one day... [see here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/214330)

Comment: Do you have a specific reason to use 1904 dates? Your example has nothing that implies it to be necessary. I have always taken this to be a "compatibility setting"

Comment: @Hannu My example was created just for a simple demonstration. Yes I would like to use other features (like time differences) in the same workbook. That' why I need 1904 dates.
My question is a bit theoretic. I am not interested in the workarounds like "separate your thing into multiple workbooks" or so. I am curious about that if it is a known bug in excel or not, and if there are more drawbacks of using 1904 date system.